# unable to load large pandas df (68 milli records) into tf Dataset

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

I have a large pandas df with 68 million records and I am this into tf Dataset, but seeing memory issues, tried with different machine types but the issue persist, is there a better/efficient way to load a large pandas dataset into tf Dataset, appreciate ur inputs.

```
tf_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
            (
                (
                    tf.constant([input_pdf['inputs'][ind] for ind in input_pdf.index]),
                    tf.constant([input_pdf['cats'][ind] for ind in input_pdf.index]),
                    tf.constant([input_pdf['brands'][ind] for ind in input_pdf.index]),
                    tf.constant([input_pdf['colors'][ind] for ind in input_pdf.index]),
                    tf.constant([input_pdf['thd_depts'][ind] for ind in input_pdf.index]),
                    tf.constant([input_pdf['thd_classes'][ind] for ind in input_pdf.index]),
                    tf.constant([input_pdf['mfg_names'][ind] for ind in input_pdf.index]),
                    tf.constant([input_pdf['dept_names'][ind] for ind in input_pdf.index]),
                    tf.constant([input_pdf['class_descs'][ind] for ind in input_pdf.index]),
                    tf.constant([input_pdf['descriptions'][ind] for ind in input_pdf.index]),
                    tf.constant([input_pdf['L1s'][ind] for ind in input_pdf.index]),
                    tf.constant([input_pdf['L1_2s'][ind] for ind in input_pdf.index]),
                    tf.constant([input_pdf['L1_3s'][ind] for ind in input_pdf.index]),
                    tf.constant([str(input_pdf['session_id'][ind]) for ind in input_pdf.index]),
                ),

                [[[int(input_pdf['target'][ind].replace('[', '').replace(']', ''))],
                  [int(input_pdf['taxonomy'][ind])],
                  [int(input_pdf['target_L1'][ind])], [int(input_pdf['target_L1_2'][ind])],
                  [int(input_pdf['target_L1_3'][ind])]] for ind in input_pdf.index]
            )
        )
```

Comment: Which method is this? Have you tried [tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/make_csv_dataset)?

Comment: from_tensor_slices(...) is method to generate tf records dataset